# Search from JSON File using javascript and loading from local storage

Tags: javascript, json, html, local-storage

I am currently doing a Search page which requies users to search using a html5 forms with checkbox and a submit button to search the file. I have done the json file but I don't know how I would begin a javascript file that searches the Json file and return a match from users selecting the right checkbox or radio button.

Json file I have made so far. So If anyone could help me develop a javascript   (Array) I think to search through the Json data.

```html
{ 
 "choices": [
        {
            "id":"choices1",
   "location":"Mumbai",
   "name":"Las vagas",
               "location":"India",
               "Rating": "4",
               "events":["singing", "dancing","swimming"],
   "price":1000,
   "short_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.
   "picture":"images/pic1small.jpg",
   "long_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.
   "url":"clubnight.html"
        },
{
            "id":"choices2",
   "location":"london",
   "name":"Las momo",
               "location":"Uk",
               "Rating": "5",
               "events":["racing", "climbing","swimming"],
   "price":1000,
   "short_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.
   "picture":"images/pic1small.jpg",
   "long_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.
   "url":"clubnight2.html"
        }

  {
   "id":"choices3",
  "location":"paris",
   "name":"las ham",
               "location":"France",
               "Rating": "3",
               "events":["football", "dancing","cricket"],
   "price":1500,
   "short_descriptionLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.   "picture":"images/pic2small.jpg",
   "long_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.
   "url":" clubnight3.html"
  }
```

I think I have done the javascript part wrong. If anyone could help to create a fiddle demo to show me how I would solve this task. I am not so good at javascript but I am learning. I appreciate if anyone could help

```js
$("#search").on("click", function() {
    var choiceslocation = $("input[location=’location’]:checked").val();
    var eventsSearch = $("input[event='events']:checked").map(function() {
        return this.value;
      })
      .get();
    var needToEqual = eventsSearch.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. This might be why you are having problems. There are different sites where you can parse your JSON online. [JSON Editor Online](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/) for example. I have fixed it for you:

```
{ 
    "choices": [
        {
            "id":"choices1",
            "location":"Mumbai",
            "name":"Las vagas",
      "location":"India",
      "Rating": "4",
      "events":["singing", "dancing","swimming"],
            "price":1000,
            "short_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.",
            "picture":"images/pic1small.jpg",
            "long_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.",
            "url":"clubnight.html"
        },
{
            "id":"choices2",
            "location":"london",
            "name":"Las momo",
                      "location":"Uk",
                        "Rating": "5",
                        "events":["racing", "climbing","swimming"],
            "price":1000,
            "short_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.",
            "picture":"images/pic1small.jpg",
            "long_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.",
            "url":"clubnight2.html"
        },

        {
            "id":"choices3",
        "location":"paris",
            "name":"las ham",
                      "location":"France",
                        "Rating": "3",
                        "events":["football", "dancing","cricket"],
            "price":1500,
            "short_description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.",
            "picture":"images/pic2small.jpg",
            "long_description":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis feugiat erat sit amet pharetra interdum. Duis dictum lacus massa, sit amet malesuada neque malesuada quis. Fusce interdum elit in diam dictum, sit amet consequat diam faucibus. Aliquam scelerisque nulla vel ligula commodo auctor.",
            "url": "clubnight3.html"
        }
]

}
```

I've also still added a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bUAYp1CMAmtyx8ltnbsK?p=preview) with the base search functionality. You should be able to fill in the rest yourself. It is just a form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <form role="form">
          <div>
            <input type="email" id="search" placeholder="Start typing ....">
          </div>
  </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

And then the JavaScript which loads your JSON and loops through the results:

```
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#search').keyup(function() {

          //Get the type value
            var searchField = $('#search').val();

            // Load the JSON file
            $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
              for(var i = 0; i < data.choices.length; i++) {
                var item = data.choices[i];

                //Do the check here if the 'searchField' value is part of whatever you want to check against on 'item'
                console.log(item);
              }
            }); 
        });
      });
```

**Update**

New [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/t9pU0ymnjw3z8AXJ924r?p=preview) which includes checkboxes:

```
// Code goes here
$(window).load(function(){
        $('#search').keyup(function() {

          //Get the type value
            var searchField = $('#search').val();

            // Load the JSON file
            $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
              var html = '<div>'
              for(var i = 0; i < data.choices.length; i++) {
                var item = data.choices[i];

                //Do the check here if the 'searchField' value is part of whatever you want to check against on 'item'
                if(item.location.indexOf(searchField) > -1) {
                  html += '<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="' + item.location + '"> ' +  item.location + ' <br>';
                }
              }

              html += '</div>';
              $('#result').html(html);
            }); 
        });
      });
```

Comment: thanks for replying, however I meant to say that does it store the information in local storage. Becasue you used jquery and a server?

Comment: How would you implement a simple checkbox or radio button on the search form, e.g. location:  India, UK, France and you select one and it searches the json file.  I will try and put up my version could you check if its right. Thanks

Comment: I've created what you asked in the update of my answer. You should be able to take it from here.

Comment: I asked why you used jquery? and secondly I am trying to understand why you also used a  data server in the html section.

Comment: I am using jQuery to fetch the JSON from a file and to add the html I create in JavaScript to the DOM. It is also possible to do it without jQuery, but with it is a lot easier with. I don't know what you mean with a 'data server'.